# Is there a UI pattert to change positions of elements in a list?

Tags: android

I need to create a list of elements. The elements in the list are sorted according to a field (for instance, position). I should have a possibility to add elements in this list, to delete them and to move elements in the list. Are there any UI patters for this task in Android? Can you recommend some resources for this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: I was thinking about drag-n-drop. The problem is that you have an element in a long list and you need to drag and then somehow scroll and then drop the element. Not very convenient. In any case, thanks!

Comment: Why dont you section the list or apply something like scroll to add more, the list will be more readable and these operations (dragging,dropping, swipping out/in) will be easier and convenient to perform. Cheers!

Comment: I have the following task. I need to add element into the list (I select this element from other activity and from another list in this activity). This element is placed on top of my list. Then I should have possibility to put this element into another position in the list (and the variable position according to which I put element should be changed). The problem is that the list can be very long and thus drag-n-drop will be painful for a user.

Comment: Yes, indeed, then you are right. I cant think of any solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I added a new field to a listitem that shows the position of this item. Longclick on an item call dialog where I can change the value of this position. After that I make sorting.